# Java Interface inheritence with multiple generic bounds

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have several classes

```
    public interface Identity<I> {
        public I getId();
    }

    public interface Position<T,I> {        
        public I getId();
        public T getData();
        public int getX();  
        public int getY();
    }

    public interface SpartialIndex<T,I extends Position<T,I>> {

        public void add(T t);
        public void addAll(SpartialIndex<T,I> index);
        //
        public void remove(T t);
        public void removeAll(SpartialIndex<T,I> index);
        //
        public int size();
        //
        public SpartialIndex<T,I> getRectangle(int left,int top,int right,int bottom);
        public SpartialIndex<T,I> getCircle(int centerX,int centerY,int radius);
        //
        public void translate(SpartialIndex<T,I> index,int translateX,int translateY);

        public List<T> getClosests(int x,int y);

        public List<T> get(I id);

    }
```

But when I try to create a default implementation I can not seem to get the generics to work. I wont compile with the message.

> Bound mismatch: The type I is not a valid substitute for the bounded
>   parameter <I extends Position<T,I>> of the type SpartialIndex<T,I>

```
     public class  DefaultSpartialIndex<T,I> implements SpartialIndex<T,I> {

        public DefaultSpartialIndex() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void add(T t) { }

        @Override
        public void addAll(SpartialIndex<T,I> index) { }

        @Override
        public void remove(T t) {}

        @Override
        public void removeAll(SpartialIndex<T, I> index) { }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public SpartialIndex<T, I> getRectangle(int left, int top, int right,int bottom) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public SpartialIndex<T, I> getCircle(int centerX, int centerY, int radius) {        
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void translate(SpartialIndex<T, I> index, int translateX,int translateY) { }
        @Override
        public List<T> getClosests(int x, int y) {  
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public List<T> get(I id) {      
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a typo.

Replace:

```
public interface SpartialIndex<T,I extends Position<T,I>>
```

by:

```
public interface SpartialIndex<T,I> extends Position<T,I>
```